# Self-envelope of oscillatory sinc(x) function

Tags: derivatives

Show that equation of the curve tangentially contacting $ y= \dfrac{\sin x}{x} $ is given by $  x\,y= \pm 1 $ and find coordinates of these contact points.

EDIT1:

Apologies. I did not properly convey my question.. in haste. The above can be treated deleted or kept that way for relevance. Freshly asking the following question:

Just as for example we have precessing elliptical orbits as a result of a single differential equation that carry a self-envelope ( a circle touching all perigees) , I imagined that the differential equation of sinc(x)  should have a procedure of capturing its own envelope/envelopes. So actually I wanted to be able to ask how to find self-envelopes given its derivative/DE:

$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{\cos x}{x}-\dfrac{\sin x }{x^2} $$

But how now to take off.. we have no single parameter to eliminate and so on.

Regards

Narasimham

Comment: How is "*the curve tangentially contacting*" defined? There is a different tangent at each point of the graph of $\text{sinc}(x)$. Maybe you meant to ask "Show that the hyperbolas with equations $xy=\pm 1$ are tangent to the graph of $\text{sinc}(x)$ and find the coordinates of the tangency points". On the other hand this is pretty trivial: if $xy=\sin x$ then $|xy|=|\sin x|\leq 1$ and equality holds only where $|\sin x|=1$.

Comment: There is no "**the** curve". You can ask about whether the given curve is "**a** curve tangentially contacting".

Comment: You should improve you question with more details about your work and what you have tried. Otherwise it will be eligible for downvoting and closing. Follow the given suggestions and show your work on that here, we’ll take a look to it.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

According to the suggestions given in the comments by Jack and Arthur, we need to check that

- $\frac{\sin x}x=\pm \frac1x$ determine intersection points
- at that point the two curves are tangent (by derivative)

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, the "tangentially contacting" curve is not unique, and we will just show that $ xy=\pm1$ is a possible solution.

We express the tangency condition by equating the function values and first derivative values:

$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=\pm\dfrac1x,
\\\dfrac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}=\mp\dfrac1{x^2}.\end{cases}$$

We can reject the point $x=0$. Then the first equation gives $\color{green}{\sin x=\pm1}$, which implies $\cos x=0$. With this, the second equation is fulfilled.

---

**Variant:**

The equations of the two curves can be written in the forms

$$xy=\sin x,\\xy=\pm1$$ and the equality of the derivatives of $y$ is implied by the equality of the derivatives of $xy$ (as $(xy)'=y+xy'$). The system is just

$$\begin{cases}\sin x=\pm1,
\\\cos x=0.\end{cases}$$

---

**Update:**

Turn the equation to that of a family by introducing a phase shift, and eliminate this parameter:

$$\begin{cases}xy=\sin(x+t),\\0=\cos(x+t)\end{cases}$$ gives you an envelope:

$$xy=\pm1.$$

A rescaling

$$xy=\sin(tx)$$ would also work.

But other parameterizations can give other envelopes.

Comment: The solution here is known. Can we have a procedure valid for any given $f(x,y)=0?$

Comment: @Narasimham: you should have kept the initial question and asked another. As already said, there is no unique solution, hence no general procedure. You have to cleverly introduce a parameter that turns the curve in a family.